# How can I do pub/sub by type?

Tags: scala, akka

I want to be able to subscribe to an "Exchange" (similar to subscribing by hash in RabbitMQ on a topical exchange if you are familiar), And after that point, all messages published to the exchange of the given type are forwarded to the subscribers. So essentially each type represents a channel.

I've been able to get the test to pass using a case object (just got it working first and now refactoring to a proper design). But using a case class, I'm not sure how to do it. I can create a new instantiation of the class and pass it in. However, I want to just pass in the type, not an object of it. And then match based on type.

I'm considering just passing in an object of the class and holding it to match against if its the same type, but that seems like I'm just duct taping things together because I don't know what I am doing. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
describe("Subscribe") {
  it("should add the subscriber to the list of subscribers for the given channel (message type)", LibraryTest) {
    import lib.exchange.ExchangeInterface.{ TestCommand, Subscribe }

    val exchange = TestActorRef(new Exchange)
    val probe = TestProbe()
    exchange ! Subscribe(probe.ref, /*Insert Type Here*/)
    awaitCond(exchange.underlyingActor.subscribers.get(/* Channel/Type */).get.contains(probe.ref))
  }
}

object ExchangeInterface {
  case class Subscribe(subscriber: ActorRef, channel: Command)

  trait Command
  case class TestCommand(message: Any) extends Command
}

class Exchange extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import ExchangeInterface.{ Command, Subscribe }

  val name = self.path.name
  var subscribers = HashMap[Any, Set[ActorRef]]()
  def receive = {
    case Subscribe(subscriber: ActorRef, channel: Command) => subscribers(channel) += subscriber
  }
}
```

Comment: IMO you're testing the wrong thing. It doesn't matter _How_ the Exchange is implemented, but that it produces the right results. Test that the semantics of the Exchange works as intended instead of testing the implementation itself, this will pay off bigtime in the long run, when you change implementation.

Comment: I appreciate your being candid. That's something I learned before, but hadn't realized I was doing it in this case. Would you suggest that my tests simply subscribe then listen for a message coming through on the channel... and not testing intermediate steps between that happening?

Comment: Yes, test the externally observable behaviors. You can test that multiple subscriptions of the same reference doesn't yield multiple messages etc. Happy hAkking!

Comment: Thanks for that. I've reworked this and many of my other tests using that thinking. And it's reduced my amount of test code significantly (which definitely lowers maintenance costs)... not to mention that this has really brought a bigger issue to my attention. My test code was under constant flux in some areas, because the implementation of core algorithms has been evolving as new requirements come in... with this way of testing, I can see that I'll mostly only need to add tests to a Spec rather than rework all of them when it changes. Thanks again.

Comment: You are more than welcome, have fun!

Comment: For anyone reading, there's something else you may like to know. Doing what Viktor said has also just mopped up a ton of other unnecessary features I had. I had a bunch of boilerplate for dealing with non-determinism in message sequencing (getting messages before an actor is initialized)... and just testing that at a higher level just made obvious so many design flaws. Had my brain on the wrong level of abstraction by testing the way I was. And as a result, my design was all off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing in types, objects you could simply pass in the fully qualified name of the class. It should work[*], and would simplify things a bit:

```
exchange ! Subscribe(probe.ref, classOf[TestCommand].getName)

[...]

var subscribers = mutable.HashMap[String, Set[ActorRef]]()
def receive = {
  case Subscribe(subscriber: ActorRef, channel: String) => subscribers(channel) += subscriber
}
```

If you want a bit of type safety and not have just Strings flying around:

```
case class Channel(name: String)
object Channel{
  def from(clazz: Class[_]) = Channel(clazz.getName)
}

object ExchangeInterface {
  case class Subscribe(subscriber: ActorRef, channel: String)

  trait Command {
    def channel = Channel.from(this.getClass)
  }
  case class TestCommand(message: Any) extends Command
}

class Exchange extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import ExchangeInterface.Subscribe

  val name = self.path.name
  var subscribers = mutable.HashMap[Channel, Set[ActorRef]]()
  def receive = {
    case Subscribe(subscriber: ActorRef, channel: Channel) => subscribers(channel) += subscriber
  }
}
```

This gives you two ways of subscribing to a channel:

```
exchange ! Subscribe(probe.ref, Channel.from(classOf[TestCommand]))

val command = TestCommand("Message")
exchange ! Subscribe(probe.ref, command.channel)
```

---

[*] It won't work with generics that have their types erased at compile time. So java.util.ArrayList[Int] will be the same as java.util.ArrayList[String].